# What is the best option for Mindstorms EV3 remote control for motors?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, remote-control

I have never experimented with remote controlling EV3 but I wonder what is the best way to use it, especially in the case when I'd like to control large and medium motors parallel as well, possibly from relatively long distance.
As far as I know, there are different possibilities with respective drawbacks:

- Use IR remote: short range (by the way, it is necessary to direct the
  IR beam directly into the "face" of the IR receiver?)
- Use mobile app
  via Bluetooth: difficult to direct multiple motors at the same time
  (?)

Alternatively, is controlling over WiFi (assuming WiFi dongle in the brick) working?

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, the IR remote has a relatively short range. You must not direct the IR beam directly in front of the IR receiver but it is working much better if you do. If you're on the back of the receiver for example it is possible that's your signal won't be received.

I'm controlling EV3 robots over WiFi. That's working very well. I'm using the [EDIMAX EW-7811UN Wireless USB Adapter](http://amzn.to/2kKinIn) that is working without any modifications on the EV3 with the latest firmware (1.09E in my case).

I think that's worth a try but depends of course on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you kindly detail a bit the main steps of remote control over WiFi? Shall I write a complete program for it (as far as I know neither the IR remote nor the app is capable of handling WiFi). By the way, my goal is to construct and direct a small vehicle with wheels and a gripping arm (this latter is the one that is driven by the medium motor).